# Were there any other Resurrection Stones in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

The Deathly Hallows consist of 3 artifacts said to have made by Death itself: The Elder Wand, The Resurrection Stone and The Invisibility Cloak. We have already seen that The Elder Wand is, although very powerful, a wand, which is common item among wizards. The same can be said about The Invisibility Cloak, a more powerful version of ordinary invisibility cloaks used among wizards.

However, I do not recall any mentions of resurrection stones other than the Deathly Hallow itself. Has there been any canon mentions that there were any?

Comment: Not enough for a proper answer: *Presumably*. The truth about the Deathly Hallows is that they are part of a story -- one of the stories recorded by Beadle the Bard as part of a kind of wizarding fairy tale or morality story. Death never made a wand or a cloak or a resurrexion stone. They are most likely ordinary, though quite powerful  magical artifacts around which a story got written. We have no sure knowledge that the three brothers are real persons, and we don't know with certainly if the three artifacts were made at the same time or not. It is entirely possible that there are other...

Comment: (cont)... ressurexion stones just as there other wands and other invisibility cloaks. I say "presumably" because the elder wand is not the *first wand* and the invisibility cloak is not the *first cloak*. Wands have existed for a long time, which means that whoever made the elder wand had access to a storehouse of wand lore. Likewise, whoever made the resurrexion stone would likely have had access to, er, resurrexion stone lore! I think this too speculative for it to be a proper answer, unless JKR has granted her QSS - her  quod scripsit scripsit.

Comment: @elemtilas - Harry's invisibility cloak is described as being as very unique item. There are invisibility cloaks made even today, but none is even close to the quality and functionality of Harry's, so there is defo something extraordinary about both it and Harry (it was implied it was his family's heirloom). Wand in itself cannot be more or less powerful, just more or less "in sync" with the owner, with materials it's made of giving it certain traits and characteristics. Wand's power is related to - literally - how much power one can pour through it. Of course, it's simplified description.

Comment: @AcePL -- No disagreement here! I'd only note that even Harry's cloak, as awesome as it is, is really not foolproof. After all, several folks can see through the cloak, Dumbledore, Mrs Norris and perhaps Snape. Lockhart, Malfoy and Fudge seem clueless. If two professors and a cat can see right through it, I doubt very much that this cloak will be impenetrable to Death! So yeah, a fantastic piece of magical craft, and may well have been connected with the Peverell brothers, but obviously not some kind of "supernatural" artifact.

Comment: @elemtilas Is there any evidence that any of the three you mentioned can actually see through the Cloak?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist -- Sure. Mrs Norris follows Harry; Snape reaches out as if to pluck away a covering cloth; Dumbledore looks right at the trio as he addresses them. Fudge & Malfoy look confused. Note: it was Quirrel not Lockhart that Harry saw with Snape.

Comment: @elemtilas I'd argue that Snape unsuccessfully snatching at the cloak very much implies that he CAN'T see through it, despite sensing that someone was there (Snape was aware of James' cloak, and while it's never elaborated on exactly how legilimency works, it's possible he could "sense" someone's presence using it). Similarly, it's never outright stated that the cat CAN see through the cloak and it's just as likely she can smell him, hear him or sense his movement (as real cats are far more capable of these than humans, and actually have worse eyesight than us). Dumbledore is... Dumbledore ;)

Comment: Moody's magical eye that could see through the cloak as well

Answer (score 1):

Not as *stones*, no, but we most definitely see two things which, like the Stone, can show you a speaking, intelligent shade of a dead loved one. The first is another obscure bit of magic to most wizards: Priori Incantatum. As we saw in Goblet of Fire, anybody killed with a wand involved in the type of wizard's duel that produces the PI effect will pop out as a shade with opinions and reactions that seem genuine. Like the images created by the Stone, they seem real enough for the moment (even going so far as to make plans for how they can help Harry), but fade away after the effect is gone.

The other is, like wands, something very commonplace that wizards take entirely for granted: magical portraits. We see them interact with people outside their borders, react to news and information, and even take sides in the conflicts of the wizarding world (Phineas Black's portrait did both of these, spying for the Order of the Phoenix as well as clearly grieving when told of his brother's death).